# My google play store is not working.

Tags: applications, google-play-store, rooting, 4.2-jelly-bean

it shows no internet connection whereas the mobile is connected to the internet.
i tried to reboot the mobile yet the problem remains. my mobile is rooted . it was rooted before 1.5 years but the problem started 1 month before.

Comment: Were you using freedom app ?

Comment: yes i am using freedom app.

Comment: So, you must be using core service. Try to search on this site of how to resolve this situation. It has been already answered. You have to tweak HOSTS file in root directory somewhere. Find it and enjoy ?